# Angular 4 DOM Manipulation and Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

Angular has [these](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) for DOM manipulation but I'm contemplating using jQuery for these functions: closest()/children().

So,
Is there an angular function that is identical to jQuery's function closest() which basically just returns the element?

Are there any alternatives for these functions in Angular without resorting writing native JS/TS operations to achieve those things just like jQuery, which does the dirty work? Or is alright to proceed with jQuery (I'm not dealing with template manipulation anyway)? Thanks.

**Update**

1. The window.getComputerStyle could easily replicate jquery's css().
2. Regarding jquery's selector: `closest()`

```html
<div id="ample" #zero>
  <div id="xample" #first>
    <div #x>
    </div>
    <div #y>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to know what could be an alternative operation for Angular. I could only think of making a function that traverses upward which jquery already does -give or take the DIVs and the element id are dynamically added/changed/deleted.

For example, from #y I want to know its nearest parent with an ID of ample. We know that the target element has a selector of #zero but retrieving it from div #y will take DOM traversal (which jquery simplifies using closest()) or some mapping/array operations that sorts out relations of the element which may be arduous in some point.

Comment: Most cases like this one are solved with directives, bindings and ViewChild(ren) decorator, so you likely have XY problem. The question doesn't contain any information on real case and is too broad. No, it's not ok to proceed with jQuery unless it's necessary. There's a plenty of posts on jQuery+Angular.

Comment: I don't know any reason why anyone should import a hole library like jQuery and only use a few methods of it. In your case the `css()` and `closest()` method of jQuery is very easy to implement yourself, therefore no need to import a hole library unless the library is tree-shakeable.

Comment: Oh, so I DO REALLY NEED to implement this. I hoped that angular has these kind of built in functions. I just don't want to write function(s) that already exist. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery is very powerful compared to what Angular is exposing for DOM manipulation. Sometimes it's very useful and very hard to ignore in an Angular application.

You can install it in your project but the only problem is that jQuery can access the DOM globally without encapsulation, so if you want to use good practices you should only access/modify DOM of the component you are using jQuery in, if you want to access/modify DOM outside of a component, you should pass needed data as @Input or use events to notify other components as @Output.

Do not forget to declare the variable $ in your component if you have installed it globally because typescript does not know what $ is.

```
declare var $ :any;
```

Comment: Yes. I have difficulty making a decision IF I should use them at the same time as others suggested and I read on some sites that it is not recommended. I don't want to write the jquery closest() logic again.

Comment: I just modify my answer with details on why jQuery is not recommended. You have to evaluate the goods and the bads and if you use it, at least, you need to know what not to do.

Answer (score 4):

Is there is, one should avoid using jquery in Angular, here is an example how:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'sample',
    template: `
        <span #tref>I am span</span>
    `
})
export class SampleComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild("tref") tref: ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        // outputs `I am span`
        console.log(this.tref.nativeElement);
    }
}
```

The keywords for you to search would be Elementref and Viewchild

Comment: Sir, regarding the workflow in angular. Is it much preferred to be reference based? Is it wrong to ask: from a div, what is the closest parent/ancestor element with the id of x?

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery is not the angular way, but there are certain times where our hands are tied, only in those situations use jQuery. Use @viewchild or @viewchildren to get the DOM element.

span My name is XXX  #name >

In .ts file
@ViewChildren('name') components: QueryList;
console.log(this.components.toArray());

You will be able to get the DOM. If you want only DOm element use @viewchild. In case of @viewchildren it will return an array of all the DOM elements which use the same selector or template reference variable.